# Allow only specific value range in DataGridView Columns' cells

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am moving along, albeit slowly, with this project.  I have my DataGridView almost set to where I can proceed to the next section of the project.  But one last thing that I have found that I need to fix:

**Problem**

I need to limit the range of values that a user can enter into each column of the DGV.  For instance:

- columns 0 and 1 can accept values between 0-3000
- column 2 can accept values between 0-20000
- column 3 (0-1000)
- column 4 (0-320)

The DGV does not have a set number of rows as a user can add as many rows as they need with a click of a button.  I have seen examples showing similar code for setting the values range in the entire DGV or even the rows, but I have not been able to find anything or help showing how to set the range values for each column.

I have some code written for cell validating to ensure that only Integer values are entered into the DGV and that no cells are empty.  Is there a way to add to this code or modify it to also remedy my current problem?  If so, can someone provide some help to get me started?  - Thank you, Newbie.

```
Private Sub LftMtr_Data_Grid_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e _
As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
Handles LftMtr_Data_Grid.CellValidating

    Me.LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = ""
    Dim newInteger As Integer
    ' Don't try to validate the 'new row' until finished  
    ' editing since there 
    ' is not any point in validating its initial value. 
    If LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return
    If Not Integer.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), newInteger) _
        OrElse newInteger < 0 Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Cells must not be null and must equal a non-negative integer"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that your validation is virtually the same as seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) in MSDN documentation, I trust you understand what all is happening.  Note that the cell row index is accessed in the method.  The same can be done for the column index.  Since you want to validate the upper limit of cell values based on column, we will use this column index to set the upper limit to check against.

Try adding the following code after `Dim newInteger As Integer` but before your If statement:

```
Dim upperLimit As Integer = 0

Select Case e.ColumnIndex
    Case 0, 1
        upperLimit = 3000
    Case 2
        upperLimit = 20000 
    Case 3
        upperLimit = 1000
    Case 4
        upperLimit = 320
    Case Else
        Debug.WriteLine("You decide what should happen here...")
End Select
```

Lastly, modify your If statement:

```
If Not Integer.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), newInteger) _
    OrElse newInteger < 0 
    OrElse newInteger > upperLimit Then
```

This should ensure each cell checked stays within its column's accepted value range.